# how can I add a part to xml using xslt and xsltproc?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Configuration>
  <Parameter2>
  </Parameter2>
</Configuration>
```

and I'd like to add following part to my xml file between `<Configuration>` and `<Parameter2>` parts.

```
<Parameter1>
   <send>0</send>
   <interval>0</interval>
   <speed>200</speed>
</Parameter1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorter solution. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Configuration/*[1]">
        <Parameter1>
            <send>0</send>
            <interval>0</interval>
            <speed>200</speed>
        </Parameter1>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Configuration>
    <Parameter1>
        <send>0</send>
        <interval>0</interval>
        <speed>200</speed>
    </Parameter1>
    <Parameter2></Parameter2>
</Configuration>
```

**Note**: If you want to add `Parameter1` only if there isn't already such element in any position, you should change the pattern for: `Configuration/*[1][not(/Configuration/Parameter1)]`

Answer (score 4):

This XSLT inserts the specified content as a child of the `Configuration` element, before `Parameter2`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Configuration">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <!--Check for the presence of Parameter1 in the config file to ensure that it does not get re-inserted if this XSLT is executed against the output-->
            <xsl:if test="not(Parameter1)">
                <Parameter1>
                    <send>0</send>
                    <interval>0</interval>
                    <speed>200</speed>
                </Parameter1>
            </xsl:if>
            <!--apply templates to children, which will copy forward Parameter2 (and Parameter1, if it already exists)-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--standard identity template, which copies all content forward-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think I'd have used copy-of rather than a recursive template doing copy for the children, but yep, this should do it. I'd vote twice if I could for being defensive about an existing Parameter1.